# SharePoint - Page Redirection

Tags: redirect, sharepoint

I have SharePoint (cloud) where there is an Intranet, for example: x.sharepoint.com/sites/intranet1. I have created a new Intranet at x.sharepoint.com/sites/intranet2.

I would like people who access Intranet 1 to be redirected to Intranet 2. How can I do this in the simplest way?

Microsoft, youtube

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try to use a SharePoint News link to make a page redirection.

1.Create a News link in intranet1. Enter intranet2 URL and post.
[image]
[image]

2.Go to Site contents->Pages. Locate the page you have just created, click in the … next to the name and then click in Make homepage.
[image]

3.In order to accomplish the steps described in this article you must install the latest version of the PnP PowerShell module, more information about how to do it can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-pnp/sharepoint-pnp-cmdlets?view=sharepoint-ps&WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-5003360).

1. Open the PowerShell command line
2. Execute the following cmdlet to connect to the SharePoint site collection where the redirect page was create.

   Connect-PnPOnline -url https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/intranet1
3. Execute the script below and update the $listItemID(the new home page ID) value and use your own.

   $listItemID = the new home page ID
   Set-PnPListItem -List "SitePages" -Identity $listItemID -Values @{
   "PromotedState"=0;
   }
   [image]